# Why this code does not works in AngularJS 1.2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code, written with Angular 1.2: http://jsfiddle.net/VmkQy/1/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    Title is: <span my-directive data-title="Test title">{{ title }}</span>
</div>

angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('myDirective', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {title:'@'},
            link: function($scope) {
                alert($scope.title);   
            }
        }
    }])
;
```

Scope has a `title` property, but it does not rendered. Why?

If I change directive config to `scope:true`, it will works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VmkQy/2/

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('myDirective', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
                $scope.title = attrs.title;
                alert($scope.title);   
            }
        }
    }])
;
```

This is a bug or feature in Angular 1.2? Older version works fine in all this cases: http://jsfiddle.net/VmkQy/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{{title}}` inside of your `<span />` gets replaced. Add  `template: "{{title}}"` to your directive and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/VmkQy/5/

Comment: Thanks! But why is this happening?

Comment: I think it's a scope problem. Meaning the `title` is not available in the isolated scope: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17900556/1503476. That explains why it works with `scope: true` as well

Comment: I asked a question myself to understand the whole scope / transclusion thing better. It might help you, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23027254/1503476