# Transclusion and scopes in angular: Why is this not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, transclusion

I have a very simple setup:

```
<pane title="mytitle">Title in parent (transcluded): {{title}}</pane>
```

and

```
angular.module('transclude', [])
 .directive('pane', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title:'@' },
      template: '<div>' +
                  '<div>Title in isolated scope: {{title}}</div>' +
                  '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>'
    };
});
```

The plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yRHcNGjQAq1NHDTuwXku

The transclusion itself is working but the `{{title}}` only gets replaced in the directive's template.
The `{{title}}` inside the transcluded element however stays empty even though the directive has a variable `title` in its scope. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of the transcluded element is not a child scope of the directive but a sibling one. This is what documentation says:

> In a typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the transclusion is not a child, but a sibling of the isolate scope.

The simplest solution in this case how you can access transcuded scope is like this:

```
.directive('pane', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        template:
            '<div>' +
                '<div>Title in isolated scope: {{title}}</div>' +
                '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$$nextSibling.title = attrs.title;
        }
    };
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ouq9B4F2qFPh557708Q1?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

@dfsq is correct about:

> The scope of the transcluded element is not a child scope of the
>   directive but a sibling one

I'd like to add more comments why this is the expected behavior of angularJs. As the docs says:

> In a typical setup the widget creates an isolate scope, but the
>   transclusion is not a child, but a sibling of the isolate scope. This
>   makes it possible for the widget to have private state, and the
>   transclusion to be bound to the parent (pre-isolate) scope.

The transcluded content inside the directive is arbitrary, it **should not** have knowledge about the directive's isolate scope, otherwise, we would create a **tight coupling code**. Because for the transcluded content to work, the content must know the implementation details of your directive (what is available to use).

If you decide that the content **belongs** to the directive. You have 2 options:

1) Make the content part of the template

```
    angular.module('transclude', [])
         .directive('pane', function(){
            return {
              restrict: 'E',
              transclude: true,
              scope: { title:'@' },
              template: '<div>' +
                          '<div>Title in isolated scope: {{title}}</div>' +
                          '<div>' +
                             ' Title in parent (transcluded): {{title}} ' +
                         ' </div>' +
                        '</div>'
            };
   });
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJ2RG0jQyRWj0QB8xB8U?p=preview)

2) Use custom tranclusion to bind the scope yourself:

```
angular.module('transclude', [])
     .directive('pane', function(){
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          scope: { title:'@' },
          template: '<div>' +
                      '<div>Title in isolated scope: {{title}}</div>' +
                      '<div class="transclude"></div>' +
                    '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr,controller, linker) {
           linker(scope, function(clone){
                  element.find(".transclude").append(clone); // add to DOM
           });
          }
        };
    });
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wW2pYJGAcYnRgWEUBgJ?p=preview)