# isolated scope / Good way to communicate an array to the directive caller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Let's suppose this custom directive mentioned in `myHtml.tpl.html`:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

This directive is initialized with an isolated scope.

Of course, I have a controller behind `myHtml.tpl.html`.

**I want to communicate a computed array from the isolated scope to the controller's scope.**

I could have:

```
<my-directive arrayToCompute="arrayToCompute"></my-directive>
```

My isolated scope (in directive) being:

```
scope: {arrayToCompute: "="}
```

and my controller declaring this initially empty array:

```
$scope.arrayToCompute = [];
```

However, it seems pretty.....ugly..

What is a good alternative?
(I'm pointing out that I don't want to remove the scope isolation of the directive).

Comment: Do you tried $parentScope?

Comment: Nope, didn't try it. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an  It's not recommended to access a parent scope directly. Especially regarding scope variable names, generic in directive => should be specific in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to decouple this very strictly, I'd suggest introducing a *notify-callback*. E.g:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.raw      = [1, 2, 3];
  $scope.computed = null;

  $scope.setComputed = function setComputed(computed) {
    $scope.computed = computed;
  };
}]);

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      input:     '=?',
      onCompute: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      function compute(input) {
        return input.slice().reverse();
      }

      scope.$watch('input', function (nv) {
        scope.onCompute({
          computed: compute(nv)
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

with:

```
<body data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <my-directive input="raw" on-compute="setComputed(computed)"></my-directive>

  <pre>{{ raw | json }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ computed | json }}</pre>
</body>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/satavesuhiqu/1/

Comment: I don't see the usefulness of `function setComputed(computed)` (see my edit => redundancy of the name)

Comment: @Mik378 Have a look at [Function names in debuggers](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#names-in-debuggers)

Comment: Interesting :) Thanks