# Get value from directive in html table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js. I want to get value from input inside a row in table.

Below there is an input element. When i click the button (add) i need to get the value for that particular row.

view

```
   <tr ng-click="" ng-repeat='customer in customers | filter:query | orderBy: sort.field : sort.order'>

       <td ng-repeat='field in fields'>
           {{customer[field]}}
       </td>
       <td mult-ecs>
           <p class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Rs</span>
                <input class="form-control" name="debit" type="text" ng-model="customer['id'].value">
           </p>
           <button ng-click="addMulEcs(customer['id'])" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" >Add</button>
           <button ng-click="removeMulEcs(customer[id])" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" >Remove</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

controller

```
.directive('multEcs', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:false,
        scope:{
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.addMulEcs = function(id){

            }
        }
    }


}]);
```

image of table 
[image]

Comment: Try to add jsfiddle or similar. or atleast put sample customers data.

Comment: you can refer the image for the table. there is an input element in the rows along with add button

Comment: could you post a example of customer json ?

Comment: "customer"{
 "id": "1",
 "customername" : "John Doe",
 "pan" : "4e6ffh"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to controller scope's variable by binding it to directive scope.
In your case I think `one way binding` just suit your situation.

In your directive setting:

```
scope:{
          localEcsValue : "@ecsValue"
    },
```

And in your template :

```
<td mult-ecs ecs-value="customer['id'].value">
```

This will bind `scope.localEcsValue` to `customer['id'].value` in controller.

And in the `link` function you can do :

```
scope.addMulEcs = function(id){
            alert( scope.localEcsValue() )
        }
```

Be careful with using `ng-model` inside directive. As directive will create isolated scope and cause the ng-model not bind to the correct variable. [check this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an)