# How to access a directive's object in parent controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that is replaced by a form.  That form is bound to a `vm.customer` object.

Assuming this directive will be used in multiple parts of the application and each `vm.customer` object should have it's own scope, what are some ways that the parent controller can access its `vm.customer` object?

// Directive

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('rugapp')
    .directive('customer', customer);

    function customer() {
        return {
          scope: {
          },
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'rugapp/directives/customer-directive.html',
          replace: true,
          controller: 'CustomerController',
          controllerAs: 'vm'
        };
    }

})();
```

// View

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="scrollable-content section">
    <customer></customer>
  </div>
</div>
```

// Parent Controller

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('rugapp')
    .controller('CreateScheduleController', CreateScheduleController);

    function CreateScheduleController() {

        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate() {

        }

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to communicate between the directive and its parent controller is to use a directive's attribute.

In the directive, you can define a two-way binding attribute as following:

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('rugapp')
    .directive('customer', customer);

    function customer() {
        return {
          scope: {
              person: '='
          },
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'rugapp/directives/customer-directive.html',
          replace: true,
          controller: 'CustomerController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          bindToController: true // Bind the person property to the vm controller instead of the scope
        };
    }

})();
```

Then, in your view, you pass a customer object as following:

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="scrollable-content section">
    <customer person='vm.person'></customer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, you can access this variable in your parent controller:

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('rugapp')
    .controller('CreateScheduleController', CreateScheduleController);

    function CreateScheduleController($scope) {

        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            console.log($scope.vm.person) // Do somethings with the person
        }

    }

})();
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the parent controller is setting the person object here.  What I am looking for is to get the person object from the directive into the parent controller.  Is this still valid?

Comment: Yes, it's still valid because it's two-way binding. So, you can change the `$scope.person` either in the parent or in the directive. The value will be sync between them. You can read more about this in the [Angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), the Isolating the Scope of a Directive section.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Is there anything special that needs to be done when the directive is using a controllerAs syntax?  For example, instead of `person='{name: ...` I have `person='{vm.customer.name: "", vm.customer.address: "", ...'}` which doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.3.x? If so, you can use [bindToController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) option, which is one of the directive options. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I got it working.  Note that we should be logging $scope.vm.person, and not $scope.person for this to work.

Comment: Great that help :) Good notice, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a callback function, telling reusable directive to invoke once it is done with processing.

here `updateUser(user)` function of parent controller would be invoked when we click save button on directive's template.

`index.htl`

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="userDirective.js"></script>
....
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
      <user-form update-user="updateUser(user)"></user-form>
```

`app.js`

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.users = [{name: "Tars", gender: "male", email: "Tars@gmail.com"}];

  $scope.updateUser = function(user){
    $scope.users.push(user);
  }
});
```

`user-directive.html`

```
<div>
  <form novalidate class="css-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>
```

`userDirective.js`

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  function UserController($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.updateUser({
        user: angular.copy(user)
      });
    }

    $scope.reset();
  }

  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .directive('userForm', User);

  function User() {
    return {
      scope: {
        updateUser: '&'
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'user-directive.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: UserController
    };
  }
})();
```

To know more about Parent Controller and Reusable isolated scoped directive communication options refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997711/288952