# From my directive, how can I manually trigger a digest cycle on my parent scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that I would like to force render when a change is made to an underlying model programmatically. `$scope.$apply` is idiomatic. But I am unable to get the directive to render without clicking repeatedly on the UI (which presumably manually forces the digest).

Can someone help me identify how to manually trigger the digest?

Even `this.scope.$root.$apply()` has no effect.

Grabbing hold of a parent DOM node and getting the associated scope, then calling `$apply` on that from the console, does work however.

When using this DOM node approach in the code it does not work however. Why might this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to note:

1. Scopes inherit from each other prototypically and form a tree. Scopes have a reference to [$parent](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) which can be used to traverse.
2. A digest cycle is something that happens on a scope object. Ie. `$scope.$digest()`. This runs a digest on the scope, and then recursively does the same for all of the child scopes. `$scope.$apply()` is like doing `$rootScope.$digest()`. Since it starts at the root, it calls a digest on every other scope. So `$apply` might be excessive.

To answer your question, `scope.$parent.$digest()` will trigger a digest on `scope`'s parent.

---

But it seems that the triggering of the digest isn't actually your problem. `$apply` will trigger digests on all scopes, so if that isn't working for you, I don't think your problem is simply that you need a digest to be triggered.

Perhaps you don't need the whole directive to re-render, but just need a part of it to update? If so, consider data binding to some shared service like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNvYqo?editors=101).

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <one></one>
  <two></two>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('one', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: "<input ng-model='shared.val'> {{ shared.val }}",
      controller: function($scope, Shared) {
        $scope.shared = Shared;
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('two', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<p> {{ shared.val }}</p>',
      controller: function($scope, Shared) {
        $scope.shared = Shared;
      }
    };
  })
  .factory('Shared', function() {
    return {
      val: ''
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends. It sounds like `$parent` is what you want to call. `scope.$root` simply holds a reference to `$rootScope` (not your parent element scope). Short answer - try the following...

```
scope.$parent.$apply()
```

---

Longer answer - the above assumes your child directive scope inherits from your parent via `scope: true`. See SO answer [How to access parent scope from within a custom directive *with own scope* in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900556/1464112) for more detail on the topic and other possible approaches to access the parent scope. **Once you get a handle** on your parent scope, just call `$apply()` on it.

I've made an example which modifies the parent scope on a jQuery `.click()` event. Consider the following and observe the parent behavior...

```
app.directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             scope.value = 'parent'            
        }
    }
});

app.directive('child', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.value = 'child'

            elem.click(function() {
                scope.$parent.value = 'modded!!' // -- previously 'parent' 
                scope.$parent.$apply();
            })
        }
    }
});
```

---

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wfnjjkkd/) - working example