# scope.$watch not applying after successfully changing variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is getting a value passed into it from it's parent controller.

```
<hack-chart-controls counttime="vm.countInMinutes"></hack-chart-controls>
```

In the directive there are some `scope` values that are used to create a chart

```
scope.averageVbcCountPosition = { value: scope.counttime };
scope.averagePayPosition = { value: 12 };
scope.storeCountPosition = { value: 5 };
```

These values are used to pass to yet another child directive

```
<hack-annual-expenses-chart hack-employee-hourly-rate="averagePayPosition.value"
    hack-vbc-average-count-time="vbcCountTime.value"
    hack-average-count-time="averageCountPosition.value"
    hack-stores="storeCountPosition.value"
    hack-store-daily-balances="dailyBalancesCountPosition.value"
    hack-years="savingsProjectionPosition.value">
```

As you can see one of them depends on the passed in variable. I'm using a `scope.$watch` to watch when that variable changes

```
scope.$watch('counttime', function(value) {
    scope.counttime = value;
});
```

It is successfully updating as helpful from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900556/453985), but the chart doesn't update.

I tried a `scope.$apply()` and I get an error that a `$digest() is already in progress` error.  What am I missing? How can I get the directive to essentially re-render the chart?

Comment: You have some spotty code here. Just paste the complete code of where `counttime` is supposed to change and where the chart (however it is implemented) is updated. Also, what is the point of doing `.$watch("counttime", ` only to assign the same value to `$scope.counttime`?

Comment: The better question might have to do with using `ControllerAs` syntax. I'm using `var vm = this,` in the controller. But the directive can't recognize `vm`. If I could get it to recognize `vm` I wouldn't have the need to do this