# How to access parent scope in custom attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a starter in angular js.

I went through similar question [How to access parent scope from within a custom directive *with own scope* in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an)

But the answer did not worked for my simple experiment.

here is the sandbox.
http://jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1364/

```
angular.module('mod', []).
directive('myBind', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : {
      scopeVar : '@'
    },
    link : function(scope,element,attr){
      element.attr('ng-bind', scope.scopeVar);
      element.text(scope.scopeVar);
    }
  };
});


var app = angular.module('app', [ 'mod' ]);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.scopeVar = 'This is scope variable.';
  });
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

I simply want my own `my-bind` (as replica of `ng-bind`)

so value of attribute `my-bind` is a name of some scopeVariable and whenever that scope variable value changes, the content of div should get updated with that updated value.

Neither i got the parent scope variable value nor the element get the respective text.

PS : i know i should have used `=` but i just starting with `@` at least check to find scope variable and use it value.
PS : i also want to avoid using `$parent`

Comment: good to have the first solution but main and second problem binding did not worked http://jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1366/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your custom `ng-bind` as a simple directive, like this one:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="scopeVar"><br>
  <div my-bind data="scopeVar"></div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.scopeVar = "Bind me";
  }])
  .directive("myBind", function(){
    return {
      template: "<p ng-bind='myVar'></p>",
      scope: {
        myVar: "=data",
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: nice one but my directive also have various other attributes that i do not want to put into template again and again.

Comment: i could not find the 2 way binding as in ng-bind binding.. see setTimeout here http://jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1367/

Comment: also what it seems answer does not link to question well. I just want a replica of ng-bind. Like content of div should be updated whenever my-bind scope variable value changes

Comment: you said you needed multiple attributes, so that was one of the ways you could reach them. However for two-way-binding the 1st example should work quite fine (and though it was fairly obvious, i've added the input element which you can use to update the value). As a matter of fact nothing is stopping you from adding extra attributes to the directive, it only depends on how you intend to use them..