# AngularJs - Directive Using Parent Scope Vars W/ Isolate Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't even know what to ask at this point (edit: I have been informed that it's unclear that my question is "Why isn't the directive seeing attributes passed to it"), I thought I understood it. Can't seem to use parent controller's properties inside the directive (yes, they do need to be optional, but I don't think that's the issue).

I thought I create an isolate scope: `scope: {myVar: "=?"}` then simply create a myVar attribute and point it to "source" on parent controller. What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x0mukxdd/

html:

```
<my-directive isDisabledDirectiveVar = "isDisabledOuterVar" insideDirectiveTestString = "someTestString" />
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.isDisabledOuterVar = true;
    $scope.someTestString = 'blahblah I am a astring';
});

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            isDisabledDirectiveVar: '=?',
            insideDirectiveTestString: '=?'
        },
        template: '<input type = "text" ng-disabled= "isDisabledDirectiveVar"' +
            'value = "{{insideTestString}}" ></input>'
    };
});
```

Side note, reference article [here.](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope)

Comment: If you "don't know what to ask", how do you expect people to know what to answer??  Try to ask a question here...

Comment: Are you serious? The question is clearly "Why doesn't the directive see the elements passed through it from the parent controller through attributes?" Well, at least I thought it was clear, my bad if it wasn't.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "parent controller of a directive", by definition/design, a directive cannot know about actual controllers they are working under since they can be multiple directives under different controllers in same markup.

Comment: What? A directive shares a scope with its parent controller if no isolate scope is created.

Comment: yes, but can you assume your directive will always be inside that controller?

Comment: Nope. But it is in this case and it needs the parent's $scope vars.

Comment: ok, a blind google search brought this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses camelCase in javascript but converts this from dash-case in HTML.

html: `<my-directive is-disabled-directive-var="yourVar" />`

javascript: `scope: { isDisabledDirectiveVar: '=?' }`

Updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/x0mukxdd/2/

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I have read at least 5 articles on this, and I don't remember seeing this once. I definitely feel like an idiot now.

Comment: @VSO No problem! Must be 4 o'clock in your timezone, right? :)

Comment: 6:20, sitting here figuring this out after work lol, thank you again. Edit: All the examples I looked at used a one-word attribute / scope var name. I am laughing at myself pretty badly right now.