# Angular $scope not passing results to parent controller on update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my App I have an `$http.get()` request that stores data into the array `$scope.requirements` and a boolean into `$scope.requirementsFulfilled`.

I have a directive using the same controller as the page.  They both do an ng-repeat on the `$scope.requirements`.  When the requirementsFulfilled is false only the directive version shows, when true only the containing page.

The problem is when I envoke `$http.get()` after the first time the results are only being stored in the directive version.  How do I make sure this information is bound to both?

Within the controller...

```
$scope.requirementsFulfilled; 
$scope.requirements = [];

$scope.getRequirements = function(url) {
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.requirements = res.data.requirements;   
      $scope.setFulfilled( res.data.fulfilled );              
    });  
  };

$scope.submitRequirementScan = function() {
  if ($scope.checkRequirement() ) {
      $scope.getRequirements('tempjson/requiredPartsFulfilled.json');
     }
  };

$scope.setFulfilled = function( inputFulfilled ) {
   $scope.requirementsFulfilled = inputFulfilled;
  };

$scope.getRequirements('tempjson/requiredParts.json');
```

The page gets the requirements and populates the page.  Then the user takes actions which fires off `checkRequirement()` and then fetches the new json if true.  From this point only the directive is updating.

I believe that a child scope is being created for the directive, but I am not certain exactly what is happening.  Here is the entirity of the directive info.

```
.directive("operationRequirements", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "requirements/requirements.html"
    };
});
```

What is going on with it?

edit - Html for the directive

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h5>Scan Requirements</h5>
    <form ng-submit="submitRequirementScan()" ng-controller="operationCtrl">
       <label> <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode ng-hide" ng-hide="requirement.scanned"></div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" placeholder="Scan Barcode" autofocus /></label>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Scan" class="btn" />
    <table class="table table-hover">
       <tr ng-repeat="requirement in requirements | filter : unScannedFilter">
            <td>{{$index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode ng-hide" ng-hide="requirement.scanned"></div>
                <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-check ng-show" ng-show="requirement.scanned"></div>{{requirement.scanned}}     
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="requirement.scanned">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{requirement.partId}} - {{requirement.partDescription}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
 </div>
```

edit 2 -- Html that invokes the directive operation-Requirements and the on page display of the requirements hidden with ng-show.

```
<div class="row" ng-hide="requirementsFulfilled" >
    <operation-Requirements></operation-Requirements>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" ng-show="requirementsFulfilled">
       <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr ng-repeat="requirement in requirements">
                <td>{{$index + 1 }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode ng-hide" ng-hide="requirement.scanned"></div>
                    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-check ng-show" ng-show="requirement.scanned"></div>
                </td>
                <td>{{requirement.partId}} - {{requirement.partDescription}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I have added the html for both the containing page and the directive.

Comment: Where's the <operationRequirements> html for the directive on the page?

Comment: @Todd And how come your directive doesn't declare the scope variables?

Comment: @Hoyen It looks like he'll want to go with a "Parts" service which would have the the requirements & fulfilled variables. That way its available to both.

Comment: Are you assuming that updating the `$scope` in one place updates it in the other? Due to prototypical inheritance of scopes, I suspect that is not happening. Try putting breakpoints in your controller and see if `$scope.$id` is the same in both.

Comment: @Hoyen I have updated the question to include the operationRequirements directive piece.

Comment: Try this: In the directive add 'scope: false'. And in the directive's html remove ng-controller="operationCtrl". Basically you are creating a new instance of the controller in the directive that is separate from the parent. When you set scope to false, it will share the same scope as the parent.

Comment: Here's a good explanation for it in the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.  The suggestion from @Hoyen to add `'scope:false'` and remove `ng-controller`  did in fact solve the issue.

As for setting up a service, is this something I should still proceed with for cleaner code or 'best practice'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe this will help point you in the right direction. What I've done is pulled out the requirements stuff into its own service. Now you have a singleton that handles everything that deals with parts. When its updated in one place its updated everywhere. The directive no longer needs that other controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nej79OI3NrKcrkMNix3D?p=preview

```
app.service('partsService', function() {
  return {
requirementsFulfilled: false,
requirements: [],
getRequirements: function () {
  this.requirements.push({partId: 1, partDescription: 'Some Desc', scanned: false});
  this.requirements.push({partId: 2, partDescription: 'Some Desc 2', scanned: true});
},
submitScan: function (id) {
  this.requirements.filter(function (part) {
    return part.partId === id;
  }).map(function (part) {
    part.scanned = true;
  });

  this.requirementsFulfilled = this.requirements.filter(function (part) {         return !part.scanned }).length === 0;
    }
  };
 });
```