# Angular Js how to access $scope in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created directive for form controls[input, select and radio], 
Each input have default value, if $scope.answers have this input value then this value should show in input box.

Below code is not working from link fucntion

```
if($scope.answers.PC && $scope.answers.PC != '')
                {
                    element.val = $scope.answers.PC;
                }
```

Directive function

```
function textControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                queObj: '=',
                },
            template: '<div class="form-group">\n\
<label for="{{queObj._attributeName}}" class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{queObj._text}}</label>\n\
<div class="col-sm-6"><input type="text" name="{{queObj._attributeName}}" class="form-control" id="{{queObj._attributeName}}" value="{{queObj._pageAttributes.defaultValue}}"></div>\n\
</div>'
            ,
            link: function ($scope,scope, element, attrs)
            {
                if($scope.answers.PC && $scope.answers.PC != '')
                {
                    element.val = $scope.answers.PC;
                }
                console.log($scope);
            }
        };
    }
```

HTML

```
<text-control-dir data-que-obj="que.QuestionData"></text-control-dir>
```

Comment: Remove `$scope` from link parameter list and use `scope` instead. See more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: you can't access $scope inside directive... that is why it has a `scope: {queObj: '='}` section...

Comment: I want to access $scope.answers.PC in directive. I get undefined error if use scope. http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview

Comment: queObj I am passing different object. which has list of question to show on UI. but form value I am maintaining in $scope.answers object.

Comment: use scope instead $scope. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the `$scope` in the directives directly but as you have a `link` function you can access the `scope` to the respective directive. Yet you can't set values like you are doing currently `.val` is a wrong way to set:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.answers && scope.answers !== undefined) {
      element.find('input').val(scope.answers.PC); // <---this is the way to set value
    }else{
      element.find('input').val('No vales found!!!');
    }
  }
```

Where `element` is the wrapper element `div` and you have to `.find('input')`<sup>1</sup> the text input placed inside it.

<sub>1. If `jQuery` library is not included before angular, angular will use `jqLite` and where `.find()` method is restricted to have a lookup of ***tagNames*** only.</sub>

#### [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ljzsu2yVwhAOa9ym6TfU?p=preview)

---

Just saw, your scope doesn't have `answers` property. So, that won't work.